# integer overflow in a PIC -- where's the flow go?

Tags: c, int, pic, integer-overflow

Working with a Microchip 18f4620 PIC.  This should be a standard ANSI C question, though.

Say I have

```
unsigned int16 badFlow=65535 //max unsigned int16 value
```

This has a binary value of `1111 1111 1111 1111`.

if I then

```
badFlow++;
```

the bit pattern becomes `1 0000 0000 0000 0000`
17 bits.  Obviously `badFlow == 0`, but the additional flipped bit either

1. gets discarded
2. or resides at wherever `byte* flowPtr = &badFlow+2;`
   points.

I'm assuming the latter, but hoping for the former.

My problem:  a coworker has written some bad code with a counter that has been overflowing on all produced products for ~2 years.  Considering what our customers charge for use of these tools, that's a few million dollars in peril due to potentially bad data.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a bigger datatype.

Comment: @Mysticial yeah.  And that has been corrected.  I'm just trying to figure out if we need to go back and fix the past misbehaviour.

Comment: I don't think #2 is valid - `resides at wherever byte* flowPtr = &badFlow+2;`

Comment: This might be very late, but I'm curious; what is your compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arithmetic in C takes place with **values**, not bytes in memory. Your expression `badFlow++` is equivalent to `badFlow = badFlow + 1`. The right-hand side is evaluated as type `int` (due to default promotions, assuming `int` is larger than 16 bits; if `int` is only 16 bits then it would be evaluated as `unsigned int`) resulting in 65536, then when 65536 is assigned into an unsigned 16-bit variable, it is reduced modulo 65536, resulting in 0.

The important thing to get out of this answer is that `badFlow++` is not a direct operation on the memory at `&badFlow` (although it could possibly be *implemented as such* on some implementations). It's simply shorthand for an addition and assignment.

Comment: Thank you.  That was really instructive

Answer (score 5):

The most significant digit gets discarded.  Many processors will have a status register that indicates that an overflow occurred, but that is not visible from C (you'd have to work in assembly to use it)

Comment: That is visible from C. XC8 compiler will allow you to read the status register, for example. I think all of the compilers will allow that.

Comment: It's not part of standard C. Some compilers do provide a means of accessing it (usually an assembly macro), but it's system dependent.

Answer (score 4):

It will **not** overflow into memory that follows `badFlow`.

Answer (score 4):

Option 1 is correct, the overflow is silently discarded.

Answer (score 4):

Overflowing or underflowing an integer type in standard C is generally a safe operation and will not modify memory beyond the bounds of the variable being accessed. In standard C, the overflow bit is discarded, though the implementation may store it in a special overflow register or dedicated memory location. For instance, on i386 systems, overflow is signalled in the "carry flag."

**Edit**: As @aix points out, the carry flag isn't updated by every relevant i386 assembly instruction. This is an implementation detail of course; the C language doesn't give two hoots about carry flags.

**Edit 2**: And as R. points out, signed overflow is undefined behaviour, though every implementation I've seen still treats it safely.

Comment: Note that the i386 remark is only partially accurate: the INC (increment) instruction does **not** change the carry flag.

Comment: -1 this answer is plain wrong unless you qualify it with **unsigned**. Signed integer overflow is dangerous UB.

Comment: Fair enough. Updating answer.

Comment: Your update is even worse because it shows you know about UB but don't care, and because it's **wrong**. Signed overflow does not behave as modular arithmetic on gcc or other modern compilers as of 5-10 years ago.

Comment: I didn't say anything about modular arithmetic. I just said that i know of no compiler that becomes dangerous (ie. crashes, writes to the wrong memory, etc.) when presented with signed overflow. And since the original question asked about unsigned overflow, the distinction isn't really important when answering.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to `uint32` and making a new software release would be the right way to go..

Comment: yes.  definitely the plan here.  It's a big debacle to push the new release (involving travel and lots of mechanical work)  but we'll be doing it.